# Bootstrap Selectpicker

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a selectpicker, which dynamically builds dropdown values and will have 'All' as first option. I need to do select All/None when clicked on 'All' and also when remaining any options are selected/unselected, need to check/uncheck 'All'. Am able to get Select All/None with the following code. Need help in unchecking/checking 'All' when remaining options are checked/unchecked.

```
$('.selectallselstatus').click(function() {
    var firstli = $('a.selectallselstatus).parent();
    if (!firstli.hasClass('selected')) {
        $('.selectpicker.selstatusall').selectpicker('selectAll');
        $("button[data-id='selstatus']").attr('title', "All");
        $("button[data-id='selstatus']").find('> span[class="filter-option pull-left"]').text($("button[data-id='selstatus']").attr('title'));
    } else {
        $('.selectpicker.selstatusall').selectpicker('deselectAll');
    }
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using this piece of code. Hope helps for others.

```
var firstli = $('a.selectallselstatus').parent();
firstli.removeClass('selected');
var a = $('#selstatus').val();
a = a == null ? "" : a.toString().replace("-1,", "");
if((total elements in the dropdown) == a.split(",").length) {
    firstli.addClass('selected');
    $("button[data-id='selstatus']").attr('title', "All");
    $("button[data-id='selstatus']").find('> span[class="filter-option pull-left"]').text($("button[data-id='selstatus']").attr('title'));
} else {        
    var title = $("button[data-id='selstatus']").attr('title');
    if(title.indexOf("All,") > -1) title = title.replace("All, ", "");
    $("button[data-id='selstatus']").attr('title', title);
    $("button[data-id='selstatus']").find('> span[class="filter-option pull-left"]').text(title);
}
return false;
```